# JavaFX get the value of combobox populated using observableArrayList

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am populating a ComboBox using observableArrayList as follows:

```java
class Envs{

    String name;
    String value;

    Envs(String n, String v){
        name = n;
        value = v;
    }
    public String getVal(){
        return value;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

ObservableList<Envs> envList = 
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Envs("Name1", "Value1"),
        new Envs("Name2","Value2")
    );


final ComboBox env1Field = new ComboBox(envList);
env1Field.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Envs>,ListCell<Envs>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<Envs> call(ListView<Envs> param) {
        final ListCell<Envs> cell = new ListCell<Envs>(){
           @Override
            protected void updateItem(Envs t, boolean bln) {
                super.updateItem(t, bln);

                if(t != null){
                    setText(t.getName());
                }else{
                    setText(null);
                }
            } 
        };
        return cell;
    }

});
```

I had an overridden toString method in the Envs class since my Combobox is not showing the proper name (as Name1 or Name2) after the value is selected. Instead, it was showing the object HEX values. Now, How can I retrieve the "value" part of Env? If I use `env1Field.getValue()` the method, it is giving me the "name" instead of "value". I need to pass the "value" part to another method.

P.S: **I tried overriding** `changed` method and assigned new value to a static variable `ENV1` as follows:

```java
env1Field.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Envs>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Envs> observable, Envs oldValue, Envs newValue) {
        if (newValue != null){
            ENV1 = newValue.value;
        }
    }
});
```

And I am able to use the `ENV1` value. But somehow, this doesn't seem right. How can I retrieve the "value" of `env1Field`?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: that said: assuming a not-editable combo, you might need to set its buttonCell as well (see the api doc of ComboBox)

Comment: Note: I strongly recommend acquiring the habit of declaring fields as `private` in all but the most unusual circumstances. There is a question regarding the hex values in the button cell somewhere, but right now I'm too lazy to search for it...